# Can we read the text 'Testing123' using xpath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

[image]

I tried with "//div[@id='workcenterhtml']//descendant::a" , but cant read the text using getText()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you should try "//div[@id='workcenterhtml']//descendant::a/text()"